# Summarise nested fields

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm having a hard time getting a specific query right.

I have a schema following this style:

```
{
  "User":  "user1" ,
  "active": true ,
  "points": {
  "2015-07": 2 ,
  "2015-08": 5 ,
  "2015-09": 7 ,
  "2015-10": 1 ,
  "2015-11": 28 ,
  "2015-12": 5 ,
  "2016-01": 3
  }
} 

{
  "User":  "user2" ,
  "active": true ,
  "points": {
  "2015-01": 8 ,
  "2015-02": 4 ,
  "2015-09": 6 ,
  "2015-10": 12 ,
  "2015-11": 34 ,
  "2015-12": 1 ,
  "2016-01": 2
  }
}
```

How can I write a query that will return each user and the total amount of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small typo in @Tryneus' example, `.sum(...)` should go at the end. Try this one:

```
r.db('test').table('test').map(function (x) {  
  return x.merge( {points: x('points').values().sum()}) 
})
```

Comment: This solution works great. @Simon Just note that `values` is for RethinkDB 2.2+. Otherwise you may got `values is not a function` because `points` is an object, and object API doesn't have `values` for RethinkDB < 2.2

Comment: Thank you for the note @kureikain

Answer (score 1):

For those of us unfortunate enough to still be stuck with a version of RethinkDB without a `values` function, the trick is to first retrieve all keys and use map to retrieve a sequence of values:

```js
r.db("test").table("test").map(function (x) {  
  return x.merge({
    points: x("points").keys().map(function(key) {
      return x("points")(key)
    }).sum()
  }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple enough to do this with a `map`, summing the values of the "points" object in each row.  This code is in Javascript, so it should work in the Data Explorer, where `r.expr(data)` is the sequence of values you want to operate on.

```
r.expr(data).map(function (x) {
    return x.merge({points:r.sum(x('points').values())});
})
```

Comment: I tried it out in the data explorer using this command:

`r.db("db").table("users").map(function (x) {
    return x.merge({points:r.sum(x('points').values())});
})`

What am I doing wrong? The error that I get is:
_TypeError: x(...).values is not a function_

Comment: `values` on object is added on RethinkDB 2.2+ https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2945, you should update RethinkDB to use `values` on object.